# How to install Linux VM on Microsoft Hyper-V

Tags: linux, hyper-v, virtual-machines

**I am looking for step-by-step guide to do so.** I can go for any easy to work with Linux distribution , may be UBUNTU.

But Hyper-V page says it officially supports only SUSE and REDHAT, others can be done on owner's risk.

I dont need future compatibility etc as yet, just need to do some experiments, so any distribution would be fine.

FYI - I am trying BOINC installation and testing.

Answer (score 1):

To install Linux on Hyper-V, just install an OS like you would on any other machine. Create the VM, mount the ISO, and install it. They will all work. The only question is whether or not you want Hyper-V enlightenments for your VM.

Any Linux distribution with a kernel version of 2.6.35 or higher will have the latest edition of the Hyper-V integration components. You may need to add those modules to your guest, and how you do so will depend on which distribution you use.

The Hyper-V kernel modules that are in most distros are: hv_vmbus hv_storvsc hv_blkvsc hv_netvsc, additionally you may have hv_utils and hv_timesource, which are recent additions.